# Create customer programatically with difference shipping address

Tags: customer, customer-account

I create customer programatically, bellow is my code

```
$customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
$customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
$customer->setStore(Mage::app()->getStore());
$customer->setFirstname($fname);
$customer->setLastname($lname);
$customer->setEmail($email);
$customer->setPassword($password);
$customer->save(); 

$address = Mage::getModel("customer/address");
$address->setCustomerId($customer->getId());
$address->setFirstname($customer->getFirstname());
$address->setLastname($customer->getLastname());
$address->setCountryId($addressData['country']); //Country code here
$address->setRegionId($addressData['RegionId']);
$address->setCity($addressData['City']);
$address->setPostcode($addressData['Zipcode']);
$address->setTelephone($addressData['Telephone']);
$address->setFax($addressData['Fax']);
$address->setCompany($addressData['Company']);
$address->setStreet($addressData['Street']);
$address->setIsDefaultBilling('1');
$address->setIsDefaultShipping('1');
$address->setSaveInAddressBook('1'); 
try
{
    $address->save(); 
}
catch (Exception $e) 
{
    $msg = Zend_Debug::dump($e->getMessage());
}
```

It is working good but i want add different shipping address, and not set it as Default billing address, means my shipping address is difference.

How can i save shipping address in this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to use difference shipping address:

```
 <?php 
    $customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
    $customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
    $customer->setStore(Mage::app()->getStore());
    $customer->setFirstname($fname);
    $customer->setLastname($lname);
    $customer->setEmail($email);
    $customer->setPassword($password);
    $customer->save(); 
    $address = Mage::getModel("customer/address");
    $address->setCustomerId($customer->getId());
    $address->setFirstname($customer->getFirstname());
    $address->setLastname($customer->getLastname());
    $address->setCountryId($addressData['country']); //Country code here
    $address->setRegionId($addressData['RegionId']);
    $address->setCity($addressData['City']);
    $address->setPostcode($addressData['Zipcode']);
    $address->setTelephone($addressData['Telephone']);
    $address->setFax($addressData['Fax']);
    $address->setCompany($addressData['Company']);
    $address->setStreet($addressData['Street']);
    $address->setIsDefaultBilling('1');
    $address->setIsDefaultShipping('1');
    $address->setSaveInAddressBook('1'); 
    /* add shipping address */
    $shipAddress = array (
        'firstname' => 'Arun',
        'lastname' => 'Rai',
        'street' => array (
            '0' => 'Sample address part1',
            '1' => 'Sample address part2',
        ),
        'city' => 'Chandigarh',
        'region_id' => '',
        'region' => '',
        'postcode' => '160017',
        'country_id' => 'IN', /* Croatia */
        'telephone' => '7814075655',
    );
    $customAddress = Mage::getModel('customer/address');
    $customAddress->setData($shipAddress)
                ->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
                ->setIsDefaultShipping('1')
                ->setSaveInAddressBook('1');

    try
    {
        $address->save(); 
        /* save shipping address */
        $customAddress->save();
    }
    catch (Exception $e) 
    {
        $msg = Zend_Debug::dump($e->getMessage());
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: thanks @Arunendra,  can you please help to add `State/Province` because i add `State/Province` as `NY` or `GA` or `NC` and not have `State/Province`  code

Comment: You need to put State/Province  id here like = 1 or 2 etc. review this table he directory_country_region you may accept this answer (upvote ) if it's solve your problem thanks :)